# Adding javascript to module

Tags: magento-1.8, javascript

I am creating a module and right now I have created only the config.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>   
        <Namespace_moduleName>      
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </Namespace_moduleName>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And Namespace_modulename.xml:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Namespace_moduleName>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Namespace_moduleName>
    </modules>
</config>
```

What is the best practice to include a javascript file? 
Also where should I put the javascript?

Answer (score 2):

You can put the js files in the `js` folder or in the `skin` folder inside a theme. (`base/default` to make it available for all the themes.).
I would go with the `js` folder.

And to include it in a page add this to the `config.xml` file of the module.

```
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <namespace_modulename>
                <file>namespace_modulename.xml</file>
            </namespace_modulename>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
```

This will tell Magento that your module has a layout file. (`namespace_modulename.xml`).

Now create the layout file.  `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/namespace_modulename.xml` with this content.

```
<xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><js>path/to/js/file.js</js></action> <!-- path must be relative to the `js` folder -->
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

This will add the js file to all the pages.

Comment: I added the <frontend>... inside the <config> of my config.xml and the namespace_modulename.xml to app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout/ but it doesn't work.

Comment: clear the cache.

Comment: It is disabled. What I have now is (only those files):
app/etc/modules/namespace_modulename.xml
app/code/local/namespace/modulename/etc/config.xml
app/design/frontend/default/mytheme/layout/namespace_modulename.xml